# How to send DELETE request in Pycurl ?

Tags: python, urllib, python-requests, pycurl

I have no idea how to write the following curl command in python using pycurl or requests.

```
curl -X DELETE -d '{"key": "value"}' http://url/json
```

Answer (score 1):

- You could take a look at:

[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST from libcurl documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTCUSTOMREQUEST)

*Example I've used to send 'DELE file.txt' to FTP server.*

```
def delete_ftp_hash_file(self, ftp_hash_file_old):
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    delete_hash_file = 'DELE ' + ftp_hash_file_old
    sys.stderr.write("{0:.<20} : {1} \n".format('FTP command ', delete_hash_file))
    c.setopt(pycurl.URL, self.server)
    c.setopt(pycurl.USERNAME, self.username)
    c.setopt(pycurl.PASSWORD, self.password)
    c.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, True)
    c.setopt(pycurl.DEBUGFUNCTION, self.test)
    c.setopt(pycurl.CUSTOMREQUEST, delete_hash_file)
    try:
        c.perform()
    except Exception as e:
        print e
    c.close()

def test(self, debug_type, debug_msg):
    if len(debug_msg) < 300:
        print "debug(%d): %s" % (debug_type, debug_msg.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the example from `requests` quickstart](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/):

```
import json

url = 'http://url/json'
payload = {'key': 'value'}
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.delete(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
print(r.json())
```

A more literal translation of the curl command could be:

```
import os
import sys
import requests

headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
r = requests.delete("http://url/json", data=b'{"key": "value"}',
                    headers=headers)
n = os.write(sys.stdout.fileno(), r.content) # support bytes in Python 2 & 3
```